# How can I change default scheduler used by RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

As far as I know in older [RxJS 4](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) I could change default scheduler by monkey patching [`DefaultScheduler.prototype`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/concurrency/defaultscheduler.js). Is that correct or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Is this possible to achieve in newer [RxJS 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs). Because as I have seen in the sources, they use `null` as a default scheduler which can not be monkey patched. For example [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ArrayObservable.ts#L63)

So how can I change the default scheduler used by RxJS?
(for testing, debugging or just for fun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to set a default Scheduler in RxJS 5.

One reason could be that this might lead to unexpected behavior. For example have a look at `Observable.range()`. In RxJS 5 it doesn't use any scheduler unless you specifically set one, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/RangeObservable.ts#L89

So if you could use some default scheduler what behavior you'd expect from `Observable.range()`? To always use this default scheduler? And what about other operators that need to use some async scheduling? Should these pass the scheduler along to other operators that work similarly to `Observable.range()` which might behave differently than you expect?

Comment: Yes you are right, setting default scheduler doesn't make sense